# Next match in range on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use ArrayFormula to reference a list of IDs from 1 sheet, then match them to another and get information from their corresponding row.

At the moment, this is returning 1 result, but not continuing down the list of IDs, because that's not how Match works in this case

> =ArrayFormula(Index(SIHOT!F2:Q, Match(A2:A,SIHOT!F2:F, 0)+1, 1))

Answer (score 1):

Instead of combining `index` and `match`, use [`vlookup`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en), which is designed to do both things at once: find a match and return an entry from another column in the matching row. Example:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(A2:A, F2:Q, 2, 0))
```

returns an array of entries of column G (second in the range F2:Q) where the column F matches the content of column A.